# WSO2-AM 3.2.0 - OAuth token - Hash type

Tags: jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm making a request to WSO2-AM to get the OAuth Token to access the api published in the API Manager on behalf of the user. Everything is working with the big string returned in access_token but I'd like to use the short one version, probably encoded.

Request:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -u
 <consumer-key>:<consumer-secret> -k -d 
'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=<id_token>'
 https://<apim>:8243/token
```

Response:

```
{"access_token":"eyJ4NXQiOiJNell4TW1Ga09HWXdNV0kwWldObU5EY3hOR1l3WW1NNFpUQTNNV0kyTkRBe
lpHUXpOR00wWkdSbE5qSmtPREZrWkRSaU9URmtNV0ZoTXpVMlpHVmxOZyIsImtpZCI6Ik16WXhNbUZrT0dZd01XSTBaV05
tTkRjeE5HWXd....bZ-CD_r-2qkypeER7f8QMrLpozRipgHeCkpIKXx5PzSM6zBq5VjMW4EXSRg7LSu0JAJfD2UD6H4bqAiZPNiGy9vTLXc
Zr4g8WNzfKkr...
-hiAOt4SauSZxB1WWCFEZ0xyHVhbx7nAFzBVzfssF0DOYGXkc9hRJZGbG8VfiXb6PWtSfEjqJTSSY_aZWXw",
"refresh_token":"d3062fa0-1132-3532-b1b2-83c3c66136ff","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

Expected:

```
{"access_token":"400f2a54-53d8-3146-88e3-be1bf5e7450d",
"refresh_token":"c2656286-449f-369f-9793 2cee9132de9f",
"scope":"default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

What I'm doing wrong that is not returning the short one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that the expected by you `access_token` is the *Opaque(Reference) Access Token*, described in this WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 documentation: [Secure APIs using OAuth2 Opaque(Reference) Access Tokens](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/api-security/oauth2/access-token-types/opaque-tokens/).
But, according to the [Release notes](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/getting-started/about-this-release/#removed-features-and-functionalities), from WSO2 API Manager **3.2.0**, they removed this type of access token:

> Out-of-the-box support to generate an opaque access token via the Developer Portal has been removed. Application Developers can create applications that only generate a JWT type access tokens.

So, *the big string*, you get is nothing more, like this JWT token, described here in documentation: [JWT (Self Contained) Access Tokens](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-security/oauth2/access-token-types/jwt-tokens/), which you can decode on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) site.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode your long JWT from https://jwt.io/ and get the JTI value of it as the short one which will look similar to 400f2a54-53d8-3146-88e3-be1bf5e7450d.

Refer to the example shown below.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

As you were referring to the short token. It is the opaque token and APIM 3.2.0 It is not shown while you creating the Application. You can get the default Token (opaque) By the WSO2 carbon management console.

Change Token Issuer to Default from JWT in ISP list for particular Application that you need to use.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uTc6.png)

Where I am generating opaque (Short) Token in APIM 4.0.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq0y8.png)